# Time Complexity of accessing [class variables,functions] vs [dictionary values,keys] in Python3

Tags: python-3.x, algorithm, class, hash, hashmap

I implemented trie by using classes and by dictionaries separately and got different runtimes.Trie implementation with dictionaries worked about 2.5 times faster than trie with classes when input size is large(array of ~100000 integers)

I am trying to implement trie.I used classes and code gave me Time Limit Exceeded error many times.After changing the code and implementing trie by using dictionaries,time complexity improved drastically.What is the reason? Accessing keys and values of a dictionary is considered O(1).But classes worked slower than dictionaries.Is accessing fields of a class O(1)? My first and second codes were

Trie implementation with classes

```
class TrieNode:
    def __init__(self):
        self.children={}

class Trie:
    def __init__(self):
        self.root=TrieNode()

    def addNum(self,num):
        node=self.root
        for i in range(31,-1,-1):
            bit=(num>>i)&1
            if bit not in node.children:
                node.children[bit]=TrieNode()
            node=node.children[bit]

    def getMax(self,num,cur,bit,node):
        if not node.children:
            return cur
        numbit=(num>>bit)&1
        res=-1
        if numbit^1 in node.children:
            res=self.getMax(num,cur*2+1,bit-1,node.children[numbit^1])
        elif numbit^0 in node.children:
            res=self.getMax(num,cur*2,bit-1,node.children[numbit^0])
        return res
```

Trie implementation with dictionaries

```
class Trie:
    def __init__(self):
        self.root={}

    def addNum(self,num):
        node=self.root
        for i in range(31,-1,-1):
            bit=(num>>i)&1
            node.setdefault(bit,{})
            node=node[bit]

    def getMax(self,num,bit):
        cur,node=0,self.root
        for i in range(31,-1,-1):
            numbit=(num>>i)&1
            if numbit^1 in node:
                cur,node=cur*2+1,node[numbit^1]
            elif numbit^0 in node:
                cur,node=cur*2,node[numbit^0]
        return cur
```

Answer (score 0):

> After changing the code and implementing trie by using dictionaries...

There are more changes to the code than only that:

- `getMax` has fewer arguments.
- `getMax` no longer calls itself: the removed recursion saves on stack operations
- using `setdefault` instead of an `if` construct

So the comparison you made is not fair if you wanted to see the difference between defining a `TreeNode` class or not.

And still:

- The class implementation used a dict (`children`) too, so the class is just an additional layer that doesn't bring any benefit. In the end all essential operations still happen on a dict in both versions, but the class version needs to create and access an additional level (`children`) to get to the dict.

> ...time complexity improved drastically

You cannot measure time complexity by looking at how long it takes for code to complete.

The time complexity is actually the same for both versions, but that tells you nothing about how long code will run for an input size of 100000, nor how that time would compare to another algorithm. Time complexity only tells us how the running time evolves when the input size increases to infinity (asymptotically), and it is expected that two algorithms with the same time complexity can have completely different times to complete, even for large inputs. Note that O(100 + 10000) = O().